# Add image to left side of action bar ?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I need add a image in between navigation button and drop-down in action-bar.How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: or you can make your custom layout for this particular activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call `setIcon()` it will change the icon

```
getActionBar();
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) for more detail